# straight quotes don't read in gdata:::read.xls

Tags: r, gdata

I am playing with reading in text in different formats and I noticed that using a csv file that looks like this:

```
A   B
The dog "was" here  yes
```

the `read.csv` function reads the data in how I'd expect with the straight quotes.

```
> read.csv("Book1.csv")
                   A    B
1 The dog "was" here yes
```

However, when converting the file as a .xlsx and using `gdata:::read.xls` the quotes are read in as `\\`, not as expected.  Is this an error in something I'm not setting?  If not is this something I should report to the package maintainer?

```
library(gdata)
read.xls("Book1.xlsx")

> read.xls("Book1.xlsx")
                     A    B
1 The dog \\was\\ here yes
```

Comment: You meant `gdata:::read.xls` right?

Comment: Yeah let me fix that.

Comment: I can't try out the function at the moment but it seems there is a warning about this in the help page for read.xls.  I quote: _If you have quotes in your data which confuse the process you may
     wish to use ‘read.xls(..., quote = '')’.  This will cause the
     quotes to be regarded as data and you will have to then handle the
     quotes yourself after reading the file in._

Comment: Yeah but that messes with a host of other things.  I think it's probably part of the function.  I think I'll use `x <- gsub("\\\\", "\"", x)` to accomplish what I'm after.  Good catch, thank you.

Comment: Also read the caveats under gdata on this page: http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows